# Hibernate JPA and javax persistence conflicts while upgrading to Spring 5.3.20

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We're trying to upgrade the spring version on our existing project to 5.3.20 from 3.0.3. We've been stuck on the same errors and circling around it for weeks now. We're using normal Spring framework. It's not a maven project. I've also updated hibernate from 3.x to 5.1.2 (I've also tried using 5.6.9 and went through the same issue) From all that I've done until now to fix this issue, this is what I've understood:

I'm using hibernate JPA 2.1 api 1.0.2 and javax persistance api 2.2. There are 2 issues. When I use both together I get this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

when I try removing javax persistence - I get this TableGenerators class not found error. and when I remove JPA I get JoinColoumns.ForeignKey() method not found error. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Is there a way to exclude certain classes from these jars if it's not a maven project? Is the actual issue something else altogether?

Stacktrace

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Please excuse my format of asking the question. I understand it's not up to the mark. Really need the help. Thanks.

Comment: remove `hibernate JPA 2.1 api 1.0.2` and keep the `javax.persistence-api`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey; - this is the error i'm getting when I remove JPA 2.1. How do you suggest this can be fixed?

Comment: Provide a full list of your spring, hibernate, javax dependencies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Spring - aop, context, context support, beans, core, data-commons(2.7), data JPA(2.7), expressions, JDBC, orm, tx, web, webmvc (everything else is 5.3.20) 
Hibernate core - 5.4.24, Hibernate JPA - 2.1 api - 1.0.2, Hibernate commons annotation -5.1.2
javax.persistence- api - 2.2, javax.activation -api-1..2.0, javax servlet 3.0